# Connection is disposed automatically

Tags: c#, .net

this may seem trivial but it's really bothering me.
I have started today using Dapper within an MVC project and created a very simple POCO object; when I run this project thought, i get the following error message:

> Cannot access a disposed object
>
> Object name: 'OracleConnection'.

Here is the code:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    readonly IDbConnection sqlConn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LogDbContext"].ConnectionString);
    readonly string selectLog = "select * from LOG";
    readonly string insertLog = "insert into LOG (ID, Address) values (:ID, :Address)";

    // GET: Log
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (sqlConn)
        {
            sqlConn.Open();

            //IEnumerable log = sqlConn.Query(selectLog);

            IEnumerable<Log> log = sqlConn.Query<Log>(selectLog);

            foreach (var item in log)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }

        }

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        using (sqlConn)
        {
            sqlConn.Open();

            var log = new Log()
            {
                ID = 1,
                Address = "test"
            };

            sqlConn.Execute(insertLog, log);

        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

it seems that placing the "sqlConn" into the using statement is making it dispose automatically so when the function is running it again it can't work on the connection.

How can I prevent this? I'd prefer not to open and close the connection manually each time I need it.

---

**UPDATE**

Using all the help provided from the answers below (all correct) I ended up using a constructor for the class to instantiate a new connection every time the class had to be used.

```
    //removed the wrong static attribute and the instantiation
    readonly IDbConnection sqlConn;
    readonly string selectLog = "select * from LOG";
    readonly string insertLog = "insert into LOG (ID, Address) values (:ID, :Address)";

    // Created a constructor to instantiate the connection everytime the controller gets called
    public LogController()
    {
         sqlConn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LogDbContext"].ConnectionString);
    }
```

Comment: Off topic: Why is everybody using `ConfigurationManager.XYZ["Value"]` with the danger of misspelling `Value` instead of simply using the automatically generated properties available through `Properties.Settings.Default`? I really don't get it...

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Please argument. How could I use that prop?

Comment: `string connStr = Properties.Settings.Default.LogDbContext;` in your case. Generally, for every setting you create, be it a connection string, an application or a user setting, Visual Studio adds a property to a settings class. The default instance of that class is `Properties.Settings.Default`. User settings are read/write, application settings and connection strings are read-only. You can thus even set the user settings *and* save the settings using `Properties.Settings.Default.Save`. I don't get why you'd do it any other way if the builtin mechanism is so simple to use.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar sorry for the stupid question, which namespace Properties.Settings fall in?

Comment: `Properties` is in the default namespace of your application. You should be fine simply writing `Properties.Settings.Default.XYZ` *unless* the current class is in a different namespace than the default namespace of your project. You could also type `global::` and then click your way through intellisense to find the namespace.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I guessed it but I asked since I can't find it. My controller is in the MyApp.Controller, but neither there nor in MyApp namespace I found that Properties. Strange

Comment: Hm. It should be there if you created the settings using the `Settings` section in the project properties. It will not be there if you edited the app.config file manually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104432/discussion-between-alexander-d-and-thorsten-dittmar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is exactly what `using` is intended to do. It disposes IDisposable objects as soon as the using block is exited.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

This is good practice for SQL connections however - connection pooling ensures that there is no significant delay in opening a new connection, as the DB layer keeps one or more ready in the pool.

I would modify your code as follows:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    static readonly string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LogDbContext"].ConnectionString;
    readonly string selectLog = "select * from LOG";
    readonly string insertLog = "insert into LOG (ID, Address) values (:ID, :Address)";

    // GET: Log
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (var sqlConn = new OracleConnection(connStr))
        {
            sqlConn.Open();

            //IEnumerable log = sqlConn.Query(selectLog);

            IEnumerable<Log> log = sqlConn.Query<Log>(selectLog);

            foreach (var item in log)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }

        }

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        using (var sqlConn = new OracleConnection(connStr))
        {
            sqlConn.Open();

            var log = new Log()
            {
                ID = 1,
                Address = "test"
            };

            sqlConn.Execute(insertLog, log);

        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is useful. But since I may have a very large number of methods using the connection I'd like to have a global object instead of instantiating a new one each time

Comment: That's not best practice. Can you explain why you'd prefer to do that?

Comment: I'm used to do in a different way (not that's the best way). I have been provided with a class that inherits from IDisposable which contains IDbCommand, IDbConnection etc.
My DAL class (raw SQL) then inherits from that class and uses the 

'internal MyDal(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        {
        }
'

So when I create a method just calling a command in a using will do all the job

Comment: Cool, I do something similar with DAL classes too. Provided your DAL class implements IDisposable correctly, then I it should be fine to create new short-lived instances of it within `using` statements. The DB connections will still be pooled.

Answer (score 7):

You declared your `sqlConn` as `static readonly`, which means there's only a single instance of it for the entire application. Wrapping it in `using()` means that after the very first request completes the `sqlConn` gets disposed of and subsequent requests fail with `ObjectDisposedException`.

To fix this, rewrite your code as follows:

```
var connectionString = 
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LogDbContext"].ConnectionString;
using(var sqlConn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
    // ...
}
```

Now, as for you not wanting to *open* the connection each time, this is what you will have to do. Connections are precious, and have to be managed carefully: open as late as you need, close as soon as you don't need them anymore. You can always factor out your connection initialization logic into a separate method or go the Enterprise (r)(tm) way and inject it.

Comment: What's the Enterprise way? never seen someone injecting it :) It would be nice to see a little example of a connection initialization logic

Comment: injecting it would mean that your controller would take a SqlConnection as a constructor argument and use the same connection during the controllers lifespan. the point of this is to abstract away the responsibility of creating the connection or even know what type of connection it is from the controller. it's about managing dependencies and separating things that are not related.

Answer (score 7):

> it seems that placing the "sqlConn" into the using statement is making it dispose automatically

Yes, that's what the `using` statement is for.

> How can I prevent this? I'd prefer not to open and close the connection manually each time I need it.

I'd strongly recommend that you *do* open and close the connection each time you need it - but use a local variable for it, not a field. That way each operation gets a separate logical connection, so you don't need to worry about threading issues etc. Let the connection pool take care of making this efficient. I suspect you're concerned about opening a "physical" connection (making a new TCP/IP connection or whatever) on each call - but the connection pool is there to make sure that that *doesn't* happen more than it needs to.

Just create a new connection within the method:

```
using (var connection = new OracleConnection(...))
{
    ...
}
```

... and *measure* performance to check that it's satisfactory. Don't start guessing about whether you'll have a problem (and resorting to poor workarounds which cause more problems than they solve).

As an alternative to using `new`, the controller constructor could take a connection provider and ask that for a new connection, but fundamentally it's about creating a new disposable connection each time.

If for some reason you really, really don't want to dispose of the connection, just remove the `using` statement - but be *very* aware that you'll need to handle concurrency yourself. You almost certainly don't want to do that.

Comment: This seems really interesting, may you show a simple code for that implementation of a connection provider?

Comment: @AlexanderD: No, I'm afraid that's really beyond the scope of the question. Heck, the simplest implementation could still just call `new OracleConnection`... but the interesting details would depend on what you were trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Either use connection *locally* (within the method), that's a *preferable* way of implementation

```
public class MyController : Controller {
  // No sqlConn field

  public ActionResult Index() {
    using (IDbConnection sqlConn = new OracleConnection(...)) {
      sqlConn.Open();
      ...
    }
  }
```

Or let *object's instance*, and not *method* dispose it, in this case you have to dispose the object and thus examine your code:

```
  public class MyController : Controller, IDisposable { // note IDisposable
    // no static
    readonly IDbConnection sqlConn = new OracleConnection(...);

    public ActionResult Index() {
      // No using  
      sqlConn.Open();
      ...
    }

    protected void Dispose(Boolean disposing) {
      if (disposing) {
        sqlConn.Dispose();
      } 
    }

    public Dispose() {
      Dispose(true);

      GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
  }
```

Or let *class* itself dispose the connection, the worst, IMHO, way:

```
  public class MyController : Controller {
    static readonly IDbConnection sqlConn = new OracleConnection(...);

    public ActionResult Index() {
      // No using  
      sqlConn.Open();
      ...
    }

    private static void OnExit(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
      sqlConn.Dispose();
    }

    static MyController() {
      Application.ApplicationExit += OnExit;
    }
  }
```

Whatever method you've chosen do not *mix* these three models (your current code is a mixture of the 1st and 3d implementations).